# Using .First() and .Count() broke a IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, .net, list, ienumerable

This is my code :

```
protected IEnumerable<Hotel> Hotels;
protected Hotel Hotel;

Hotels = from Hotel hotel in new Hotels()
         select hotel;

Response.Write("RES " + Hotels.Count() + "<br />");
if (Hotels.Count() > 0)
{
    Hotel = Hotels.First();
}
Response.Write("RES " + Hotels.Count() + "<br />");
Response.Write("RES " + Hotels.Count() + "<br />");
```

Well, Hotels have 1 item on it. But the result it :

```
RES 1
RES 0
RES 1
```

Why? Seems that `.First()` make confusion with iterator? How can I fix it using IEnumberable? (without using another kind of list, I need IEnumerable).

Comment: How is Hotels populated & what is the underlying storage e.g. is it actually referencing a List<Hotel> ?

Comment: The behaviour depends on what exactly Hotels is. If it contains some reference / connection to a data source which can change, then obviously the value can change between calls to Count, or if it is implemented with yield return it could be doing anything. Try calling ToArray() on it, and then doing your counts etc on the value returned from ToArray(), then you know you have a fixed snapshot of the collection.

Comment: It might be a problem with the actual implementation of Hotels. It works on Lists, for example.

Comment: What class implements that IEnumerable? How do you initialize that `Hotels` variable? It works ok with lists arrays etc. By the way, you can use `FirstOrDefault()` extension method instead of that if construction.

Comment: Just tested it in a console app with a List, it returns 1, 1, 1 as expected.

Comment: ? I know it works with List, but it doesn't with Enumerable. That's my problem...

Comment: using `.FirstOrDefault()` it's the same...

Comment: Does `Hotels` instance implementes `ICollection<T>`? Please show how you are creating/populating `Hotels`

Comment: What is `Hotels` that you instantiating?

Comment: @markzzz: have you posted code without any modifications? Just wondering whether it even compiles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IEnumerable<String> Hotels = new List<String>{"sdsfsdf"};
    String Hotel;

    Console.WriteLine("RES " + Hotels.Count());
    if (Hotels.Count() > 0)
    {
        Hotel = Hotels.First();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("RES " + Hotels.Count());
    Console.WriteLine("RES " + Hotels.Count());
}
```

prints

```
RES 1
RES 1
RES 1
```

As expected, how are you filling the enumerable and what type are you creating it as?

If you are filling this via an un-executed queriable you might get weird behavior like this as it will pick the first useage (ie `First()` in this case).

Comment: can you post your linq statement?, also is this from a database directly?

Comment: add a .ToArray() onto the end of your linq. This will force the query to populate to memory before the .First() which means it will be performed against .net objects

Comment: Well...adding .ToArray() works! But, WHY this behaviour? Can you explain it to me?

Comment: @markzzz: ToArray() executes an underlying LINQ query and returns a collection itself, so Count() will reffer always to the same list of items

Comment: yeah sure, whats happening is that you are executing each sequential statement vs an IQueriable. What happens is that the query provider decides how to translate this to SQL, i imagine when you call first it grabs your entity as a query not an enumerable and hence clears the base collection

Comment: @markzzz: have you posted code without any modifications? Just wondering whether it even compiles? – sll just now

Comment: Oko, but why when I call Count() the third time it is still at 1? That's not clear :(

Comment: I *think* that its because when you call the first count it think the query is executed to something that isnt a collection of the specified type (ie count of the actual type is 0) and the second time it thinks its previously executed on a count so needs to recheck the DB, ie this is an optimisation the ORM would implement to reduce SQL round trips, but i could be wrong.  TBH its probably a bug in your specific ORM

Comment: @LukeMcGregor  : Am I missed a point where OP stated that he used LINQ-to-SQL query?

Answer (score 3):

No magic here. Looks like quantity of items in the `Hotels` collection changing in the time, perhaps some LINQ query with deffered execution, perhaps even LINQ-to-SQL.

Please show a full code which populates Hotels.

Answer (score 1):

The "First" method probably advances the iterator to point to the second element. Your first call to "Count" then completes the iteration on you one element sequence, and the subsequent call to count starts iteration anew. Count will always iterate the entire sequence, so it is idempotent. You need a way to reset the enumerator `Hotels.Reset()` after `First()` to make `Count()` behave correctly.

The simplest thing would probably be to make a `Reset` extension yourself, but I cannot reproduce your problem. If you have some system generated database iterator it is possible it would not reset automatically and you could use the code below. It just utilizes your own finding that a single `Count()` resets the iterator. And it would be `O(n)` to complete.

```
static class Extensions
{
    public static void Reset<T>(this IEnumerable<T> toReset )
    {
        if (toReset != null)
        {
            int i = toReset.Count();
        }
    }
}
```

But I cannot reproduce your problem:

Code below gives the correct result throughout. Have you written you own enumerator or collection?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var Response = System.Console.Out;

    var Hotels = new[]{1, 2, 3, 4};
    var Hotel = 0;

    Response.Write("RES " + Hotels.Count() + "<br />");
    if (Hotels.Count() > 0)
    {
        Hotel = Hotels.First();
    }
    Response.Write("RES " + Hotels.Count() + "<br />");
    Response.Write("RES " + Hotels.Count() + "<br />");

    Console.WriteLine( "Hotel: " + Hotel);
}
```

Comment: There is not a .Reset() method on IEnumerable, already checked :(

Comment: No, it is on the enumerator. Which collection are you using for `Hotels`? -- I can't reproduce your error using an array.

Comment: markzzz, I suppose you use some strange object as your IEnumerable<Hotel>. Probably your own implementation that messes things up.

Comment: Then I think the underlaying data source changes over time and therefore different results...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the underlying implementation, re-enumerating an IEnumerable is not guaranteed in any way to return the same value. To see why, consider this example;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IEnumerable<int> bop = RandomSequence();
    Console.WriteLine(bop.Count());
    Console.WriteLine(bop.Count());
}

private static int _seed = 0;
static IEnumerable<int> RandomSequence()
{
    var random = new Random(_seed++);
    int randomNumber;
    while ((randomNumber = random.Next(100)) != 0)
        yield return randomNumber;
}
```

This is a perfectly valid IEnumerable, and the two calls to Count() will evaluate to two different pseudo random values. The reason being that Count() re-enumerates the same IEnumerable and generates a completely different random sequence.

If you want repeatable enumerations, you will need to call `ToList()` or `ToArray` on the enumerable to store the results, and do all enumeration from the List/array which Enumerates the same way every time.